# Hidden network unsecured

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I've a question about Hidden Networks and windows.
An unsecured (no password/key of any kind) will ask for SSID when someone tries to connect to this Hidden Network from a windows (8 or 10) client?
Or, because no security has been added, if someone just select the Hidden Network in the wifi connections list, and press the "connect" button, will be able to join the wifi network without knowing the SSID?
Excuse for my poor English :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hidden SSID means an access point doesn't broadcast its SSID in beacon frames. Thus hidden means it is only not broadcasted, yet it can be "discovered" with tools capturing wireless traffic. See https://ethicalhackingblog.com/uncovering-hidden-ssids/. IIUC one must enter SSID even for hidden network.

Comment: Yes, but apart the case the SSID could be discovered with various tool, my question is more basic... "Is required to enter the SSID to join a hidden network with no security key"? Or to connect to a hidden network with no security key (WPA ecc...) even the SSID is not asked to connect? Excuse me for my poor english...

Comment: My question is if Windows will ask or not to enter the SSID for a open hidden network :)

Comment: It will ask for the SSID because it doesn't know what the SSID is since the access point does not broadcast it.